# Entendendo requisições HttpURLConnection, OutputStream, InputStream e Buffered Writers para uso de banco de dados MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, web-service

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação android que terá acesso a um banco de dados `MySQL` usando `webservice`. Vi alguns tutoriais na net e num tutorial em inglês conseguir fazer a conexão e inserção de dados, criando assim um sistema de login e de registro. Porém não consegui entender como e para que serve os códigos `HttpURLConnection`, `OutputStream`, `InputStream` e `Buffered Writer` usados no tutorial e que fizeram o bicho rodar.

Gostaria de uma explicação sobre cada um deles e de como todos juntos puderam fazer o negócio funcionar...

Comment: Prezado, isso depende de estudo. Não é dúvida (não me entenda mal ok). Não entender toda a camada de comunicação web é porque você não sabe o que os objetos fazem. Acredito que aqui no SO sua dúvida será bem vista se for pontual. Por exemplo: Porque o HttpURLConnection tem um método de timeout. Se a documentação do Android lhe faltar informação, vá na documentação da Oracle e estude o que são Streams, BufferedWriter, Reader etc.

Comment: Obrigado professor... Sou Tecnico em informatica e estudei sobre programação web html, css e php. Não me aprofundei muito no mundo da orientação em objeto. Peguei um pouco de java básico para conseguir compreender a programação android que é minha paixão e pretendo criar APP para a comunidade de minha região. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É uma pergunta complexa, mas vou tentar resumir o que cada um faz e para que serve de acordo com a documentação.

**1** - [`HttpURLConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

Esta é uma classe abstrata que contém os métodos utilizados para efetuar uma conexão `HTTP`. Ela estende a classe [`URLConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html).

**Exemplo de utilização:**

```
URL url = new URL("http://teste.com");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.connect();
```

Veja pelo exemplo que para obtermos uma instância do tipo HttpURLConnection, temos que instanciar a classe URL. Se você checar a documentação, a classe URL representa "Uniform Resource Locator", um apontamento para um lugar da Web.

Depois de instanciada a classe URL, é a classe HttpURLConnection que será responsável por efetuar a conexão a este lugar apontado.

**2** - [`OutputStream`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStream.html?hl=pt-br)

É utilizado quando você precisa escrever(write) dados para algum lugar, seja um arquivo, conexões de rede, etc. Neste caso, ele é utilizado para escrever os dados em uma conexão `HTTP`.

**Exemplo de utilização:**

```
// Antes de você escrever os dados, você precisa dizer a conexão que você vai fazer isso
conn.setDoOutput(true);
// Instancia o OutputStreamWriter usando o OutputStream da conexão que você efetuou
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
conn.getOutputStream());
// Escreve os dados para a conexão.
// Nenhum dado é escrito até que você utilize este método.
writer.write("message=" + message);
```

**3 -** [`InputStream`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html) \ [`BufferedReader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader.html)

É o oposto do `OutputStream`, ele serve para ler(read) os dados de algum lugar. Neste caso ele é utilizado para estabelecer um contrato de leitura com a conexão `HTTP`.

**Exemplo de utilização:**

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(conn.getInputStream());
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Seguindo o exemplo acima, ele faz a leitura da resposta em uma string utilizando a classe `BufferedReader`, sendo assim, ela serve para ler os dados vindo do `InputStream`.

Dito isso, você já consegue sacar para que serve a classe [`BufferedWriter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedWriter.html), seria o oposto da `BufferedReader`.

---

Fora a documentação do android, você pode dar uma olhada neste [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10117254/5263999) da comunidade em inglês.

Comment: Entendi. Ficou realmente bem claro e explanado. Agora sei o que cada código faz quando conversa com meu PHP que faz conexão com o MySQL. Embora minha pergunta não seja um pergunta 'pontual', essa resposta foi bastante útil e esclarecedora. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Obrigado amigo, se te ajudou e esclareceu suas dúvidas você pode selecionar como resposta, boa sorte!